# Tableviecells are not getting deallocted.....Memory Management issues

Tags: iphone, uitableview, memory-management, core-data

I am working on an application in which uitableviewcells of uitableview are customized which contains a textfied(contains managedobject/core data), label((contains managedobject), buttons so all are customized. i am creating uitableview dynamically using sqlite.

[My tablview UI http://grab.by/FiJ](http://grab.by/FiJ)

Similarly uitableview view contains more than 15 cells. Cells are displayed perfectly.
but i am facing problem with the memory occupied by cells.

And if i tab on next/prev the same table view is getting reloaded with new cells(also new data) using core data. But in this case previous cells(memory of cells) should be deallocted.  But memory is getting increase and increase continuously while navigating to other views(using prev/next button).

Strange thing is,
When i scroll tablview continuously up and down cells are created and created, and memory is increasing gradually.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post your -cellForRowAtIndexPath method? Hard to point a problem without seeing your code

Comment: You might not be using the proper reuse methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

works incorrectly.

Check that your cells have same cell Identifier (You can specify it in IB) that you use in code:

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"myIdentifier";
MyCell* cell = (MyCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
         if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[MyCell alloc] init] autorelease];
         }
cell.text = @"Yahoo!";
...
```

I think that this is your problem.